# Why String.replace() doesn't work with events?

Tags: javascript

Why String.replace() doesn't work with events??

```
var el = document.querySelector('input')
var pat = /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/;

el.oninput = function(){
  this.value.replace(pat, '$1-$2-$3')
}
```

Comment: What's the `el` element? Does it work with `.onblur`?

Comment: Include the relevant HTML so that we can reproduce your error.

Comment: This is tagged with Vue. This is definitely not how you would want to do this in Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay you aren't assigning it, or returning back, as you need to **set the new value**:

```
var el = document.querySelector('input')
var pat = /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/;

el.oninput = function(){
  this.value = this.value.replace(pat, '$1-$2-$3')
}
```

Comment: This question must be deleted

Comment: @MahmoudMohamedZakria No worries. This is a good question and not a dupe. So don't worry. :)

Comment: @MahmoudMohamedZakria You are always welcome buddy!